# Struct variable overflow reading text file?

Tags: c, struct, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to parse the headers of a Linux ar file. I'm using the ar_hdr struct from the ar.h file to hold the header data. I've started small by just parsing through an archive with one simple text file and assigning the header data to the struct char arrays.

```
void conciseTable(char *path)
{

    int fd, r, pos;
    struct ar_hdr header[20]; 

    //Open the file
    fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1){
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // seek to end of ARMAG
    pos = lseek(fd, SARMAG, SEEK_SET);

    r = read(fd, header[1].ar_name, 16);
    r = read(fd, header[1].ar_date, 12);
    r = read(fd, header[1].ar_uid, 6);
    r = read(fd, header[1].ar_gid, 6);
    r = read(fd, header[1].ar_mode, 8);
    r = read(fd, header[1].ar_size, 10);

    printf("%s\n", header[1].ar_name);
    printf("%s\n", header[1].ar_date);
    printf("%s\n", header[1].ar_uid);
    printf("%s\n", header[1].ar_gid);       
    printf("%s\n", header[1].ar_mode);
    printf("%s\n", header[1].ar_size);

    close(fd);
}
```

The ar file looks like this:

```
!<arch>
1-s.txt/        1390594295  50389 13361 100640  41        `
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
1-s.txt/        1390594295  50389 13361 100640  41
1390594295  50389 13361 100640  41
50389 13361 100640  41
13361 100640  41
100640  41
41
```

It looks like the arrays are overflowing into each other and I can't figure out how to stop this from happening.

Here's a [link](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/3head/ar.h/) to the ar.h man page if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign terminating 0 character before printing strings with `printf("%s\n", ...)` or you need to specify the max printed length explicitly. I.e.

```
printf("%16.16s\n", header[1].ar_name);
printf("%12.12s\n", header[1].ar_date);
printf("%6.6s\n", header[1].ar_uid);
...
```

What happened in your case is that the first printf printed the name and because there was no 0 terminating char, it continued by printing date, uid, etc. Then the second printf printed date and continued printing uid, ...

Comment: Thank you Marian. I added '/0' to the last element of each one and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the data and parse it. You need to check and then check again. I could be anything even this html page. When you are sure fit it into the struct